# Laravel Admob, Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, admob, google-client

I have a schedule that goes every night and get Admob data for that day from the official api, and store every record with a status (true or false). and it works fine.

sometimes the google token might be expired, so I'll store a record with a status false, so when the Admin login and try to see his Admob revenue I can tell him that the token is expired and you have to renew the token, he login to google -> generate a new token,When i get a new token i got redirected to the following function :

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.readonly');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report');

$client->setApplicationName('MyAPPName');

$client->setAccessType('offline');

$googleAccountKeyFilePath = storage_path('client_secret.json');

$client->setAuthConfig($googleAccountKeyFilePath);
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($request->code);

$user = auth()->user();
$user->google_token =  $request->code;
$user->save();

$service = new \Google_Service_AdMob($client);
$accountName = $user->google_account_name;
$result = $service->accounts->get($accountName);
if($result){
    //do the job and redirect with success message as we updated the token in our database
    dispatch(new UpdatedFAiledDailyRevenueBasedOnTheNewToken($user, $service ));
    request()->session()->flash('success', 'Processing this might take up to a few minutes please wait!');
    return redirect('dashboard/reports/revenue');
}
```

this function works fine, it create a service and authenticate and all fine.
when i get to the queue, I can't use the service that i passed in as a parameter and i get the following error :

`Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed`

I also tried to create a new google Client - and Admob service inside the queue and it didn't work
even though i can do it from the schedule it doesn't work if i try to create it in the queue:

```
{
        //what i want to do is to get the admob failed data and retry with them
        $failed_data = AdMobRevenue::where('status', false)->get();

        //then lets create a service
        $client = new Google_Client();

        $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.readonly');
        $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admob.report');

        $client->setApplicationName('MyAppName');

        $client->setAccessType('offline');

        $googleAccountKeyFilePath = storage_path('client_secret.json');
        
        $client->setAuthConfig($googleAccountKeyFilePath);

        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($this->user->google_token);
        $service = new \Google_Service_AdMob($client);
        $result = $service->accounts->get($accountName);
        /*=================Creating a new service didn't work==================    */
}
```

the code above will throw the following error :

```
Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.....
         }
```

Sorry for the long description, i just wanted to make everything clear, and will appreciate any help